# Dynamically adding collapsible set and nested list in jQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am adding a `listview` inside a `collapsible` dynamically. And inside that list I am trying to add a nested list. When I am clicking the `<li>` node, `pageinit` event is getting fired instead of `click` event. The click event is getting fired when we click the same `li` second time.

jsFiddle - **http://jsfiddle.net/5zJC5/**

HTML:

```
<body>
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="d" id="mainColl"></div>         
</div>
</body>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      var ul=$("#mainColl");
      var collapsible= $('<div data-role="collapsible">');
      collapsible.append('<h2>Collapsible</h2>');

      var list = $('<ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="b">');
      list.append('<li data-role="list-divider">List</li>');

      for(var j =0;j<4;j++) {
        list.append("<li>Item</li>");
      }
      collapsible.append(list);
      ul.append(collapsible);
      ul.trigger('create');
});

$("#mainColl").on("click","li",function() {
      var list = $("<ul>");
      for(var i=0;i<4;i++) {
        list.append("<li>test</li>");
      }
      $(this).append(list);
      //$(this).trigger('create');
      $(this).parent().listview('refresh');
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `list.append("<li><a href=\"#\">Item</a></li>");` instead of `list.append("<li>Item</li>");`.

Updated jSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tolis/5zJC5/6/).

In addition, note that is is not recommended to use the document ready handler in combination with jQuery Mobile. I would suggest to add an id on the jQM page and use an event handler of the 'pagebeforeshow' event.

`$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#page-id', function(){...mycode...});`

You can find a jsFiddle which includes the suggested fix [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tolis/5zJC5/8/)

At last I would like to suggest you to avoid creating dynamic parts like that. You will realize that after some time your code will become messy and hard to read.

My proposal is to use [Undescore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#template) as a template engine and make your code reusable and clean.

**EDITED to add handler on nested list items:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>jQuery Mobile Nested List</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#home-page', function () 
             {
                var collapsibleSet=$("#mainColl");
                var collapsible= $('<div data-role="collapsible"></div>');
                collapsible.append('<h2>Collapsible</h2>');

                var list = $('<ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="b"></ul>');
                list.append('<li data-role="list-divider">List</li>');

                for(var j =0;j<4;j++)
                {
                    list.append("<li><a href=\"#\">Item</a></li>");
                }
                collapsible.append(list);
                collapsibleSet.append(collapsible);
                collapsibleSet.trigger('create');
             });


            $(document).on("click","#mainColl li",function()
            {
                var list = $("<ul id=\"second-list\"></ul>");
                for(var i=0; i<4; i++)
                {
                    var listItem = $("<li id=\"list-" + i + "\"><a href=\"#\">Test</a></li>").on('click', function(){alert(this.id)})
                    list.append(listItem);
                }
                $(this).append(list);
                $(this).parent().listview('refresh');
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="home-page">
               <div data-role="content">
                   <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="d" id="mainColl">
                   </div>
               </div>
        </div>
     </body>

</html>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: But how does a nested list actually work? When we click on a nested list, a new page is created or something else happens. Because after the first level of nesting is created, the click event handler does not work on sub lists.

Comment: If I understand well you want to add a new handler on the second level lists (test items in the specific example), right?

Comment: Yeah, I want to add a new handler to second level list.

Comment: But I am retrieving the data using AJAX after the pageload, so what should be the best way to add lists dynamically?

Comment: Please check my updated answer. I have added handler on the nested list items. As per the usage of underscore js as a template engine, check this example: http://www.islandsmooth.com/2011/08/create-a-dynamic-table-from-a-template-with-javascript-and-underscore-js/